Simple Ldap Search : Invalid Host Defined Options On Prod
I use the two codes I will sample below for the same purpose. When I received the error I mentioned in the first example, I made some changes and translated the same function into the second example, but my problem was not solved.
The error I get is this: TypeError: Invalid host defined options
I'm getting this error in ldapSearch function and console.log(LDAP URL: ${url}); I can't print it out, so it might be exploding beforehand. The problem is that while these codes work smoothly in the local development environment, when we transfer them to the production environment, they give this error.
First Example
        const ldapSearch = async (adminName, distinguished, port, serverIp, adminPass, protocol) => {
            try {
                console.log('3')

                const SimpleLDAP = await import('simple-ldap-search');
                const url = protocol === 'LDAP' ? `ldap://${serverIp}:${port}` : `ldaps://${serverIp}:${port}`;
                
                console.log(`LDAP URL: ${url}`);

                const config = {
                    url,
                    base: distinguished,
                    dn: adminName,
                    password: adminPass,
                };

                console.log('LDAP Config:', config);

                let username = user_name; 
                console.log('username',username);
                if (username.includes('\\')) {
                    username = username.split('\\')[1]; 
                }
                console.log('username2',username);

                const ldap = new SimpleLDAP.default(config);
                const filter = `(sAMAccountName=${username})`;
                const attributes = ['idNumber', 'uid', 'givenName', 'sn', 'telephoneNumber', 'cn', 'dn'];

                const users = await ldap.search(filter, attributes);
                return users.length > 0;
            } catch (err) {
                console.error('LDAP search error:', err);
                return false;
            }
        };

Second Example
   const ldapSearch = async (adminName, distinguished, port, serverIp, adminPass, protocol) => {
            let ldapUserDn;
            await import('simple-ldap-search').then(async (SimpleLDAP) => {

                let url = protocol == 'LDAP' ? `ldap://${serverIp}:${port}` : `ldaps://${serverIp}:${port}`;
                console.log(`LDAP URL: ${url}`);

                const config = {
                    url: url,
                    base: distinguished,
                    dn: `${adminName}`,
                    password: adminPass,
                    // optionally pass tls options to ldapjs
                    tlsOptions: {
                        // tls options ...
                    },
                };

                const ldap = new SimpleLDAP.default(config);

                console.log('LDAP Config:', config);

                let username = user_name;
                console.log('username', username);
                if (username.includes('\\')) {
                    username = username.split('\\')[1];
                }
                console.log('username2', username);

                const filter = `(sAMAccountName=${username})`;
                const attributes = ['idNumber', 'uid', 'givenName', 'sn', 'telephoneNumber', 'cn', 'dn'];

                // using async/await
                await ldap.search(filter, attributes).then(async (users) => {

                    ldapUserDn = users[0].dn;
                }).catch((err) => {
                    console.error(err);
                });
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

            return ldapUserDn;
        };

I tried to change the code structure. Note: Normally, I do not import my libraries in this way, but due to this library (version etc.), I had to import them dynamically in this way.
